# Depth sorting of elements drawn on the screen

Tags: c++, algorithm, opengl, 2d

I have small program here in which I am drawing some elements on the window.

```
class CustomPointer{
void draw(); //draw png image on the screen
};

class CustomRectangle{
void draw(){
drawRect(); //draw Rectangle with a certain color
drawbtnImage(); //draw png image to the top right of rectangle (alphaBlending enabled)
}
};
```

**main.cpp**

```
CustomRectangle customRectangle;
CustomPointer customPointer;

void draw(){
drawBackgroundImage();
customRectangle.draw();
customPointer.draw();
}
```

When I draw my elements using the above code, I was expecting the `customPointer` to be drawn over all other elements on the screen since pointer is being drawn everything else. But my pointer is appearing over the background but goes behind the `customRectangle/btnImage`.

How do I get my `customPointer` to actually always remain over all other elements on the window?
Additionally, I was also expecting my `btnImage.draw()` to be drawn over the custom shape (like a circular button at the top right of a control). The `btnImage` is a png and has some transparency on its sides. However, instead of appearing over the rectangle, it is appearing behind it. Similar issue to fix. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not seeing any OpenGL code here, you should probably show us that. It's likely to be how you have set up your depth buffer, and/or how you actually draw things.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should some Z-Sorting zalgorithm for 2D space. Every object should have its own Z value (it can be an integer) and in global Draw method you sort using this Z order.

For top most rectangles you can set Z to some large value so that it will be always first/last .

This will also help when using transparency.

```
void drawAll() {
    sort_by_z_order();
    foreach rect in sorted_rect_list {
        draw_rect(rect)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can enable depth testing for everything but the pointer draw to get that effect:

```
void draw(){
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
drawBackgroundImage();
customRectangle.draw();
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
customPointer.draw();
}
```

that should get the desired effect